# In Angular-Kendo treeview, using a class name to hide/display a span element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I'm using the Angular-Kendo UI treeview widget in conjunction with the k-template directive to display a list of icons to the right of each tree node.

With this way of doing it, my jquery `.click()` event should hide/show my `reptIcons` span, but it's only working on the very first tree node at the top.

It should work on every node I click on, but it's reverting to the first node in my tree.

Here's an image to show exactly what I mean:

[image]

Here is the html with the `kendo-tree-view` directive and my custom `data-toggle-tree-icons` directive:

```
 <div id="" class="reports-tree" kendo-tree-view="nav.treeview"             
                k-options="nav.treeOptions"
                k-data-source="nav.reportsTreeDataSource"
                k-on-change="nav.onTreeSelect(dataItem)"     >               
    <span class="tree-node" k-template>
        {{dataItem.text}}<data-toggle-tree-icons/>
    </span>
```

and then the javascript to handle the click event:

```
     $('.reports-tree').click(function (e) {            
        $("span[class$='reptIcons'").hide();
        $("#myIcons").closest('span').css("display", "inline");
        $("#myIcons").css("margin-left", "5px");
    });
```

The directive code is:

```
 directive('toggleTreeIcons', function ($compile) {
  // on Kendo treeview, using the k-template option to embed tree icons      
  return {
      restrict: 'AE',
      templateUrl: 'app/shared/include/treeicons-include.html'
    }
 });
```

contents of treeicons-include.html

```
  <span id="myIcons" class="reptIcons" style="display: none; width: 50px;">
<a title="add new folder" ng-click="nav.addAfter(nav.selectedItem)"><i class="fa fa-folder-open"></i></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a title="add report here" ng-click="nav.addBelow(nav.selectedItem)"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a title="remove" ng-click="nav.remove(nav.selectedItem)"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a title="rename" onclick="showRename(this);"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
 </span>
```

Ideally I'd like to use the `tree-node` class above, and when a tree node is selected I would use the jQuery `.click()` to show the `myIcons` span shown above.

I'm having particular trouble figuring out the best way to wire up that `.click()` event above. And I know I'm so close to nailing this.

thank you !
Bob

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to do this in your `k-on-change="nav.onTreeSelect(dataItem)"`. I can't see the full implementation, but best guess would suggest you can do something like this, where `$(this)` ideally is the treeview node selected.

```
.onTreeSelect = function(dataItem) {
    $('.reports-tree .reptIcons').hide();
    $(this).closest('.reptIcons').css({'display : inline', 'margin-left' : '5px'})
}
```

### Edit

Per suggestion in the discussion, if the simplistic approach above will not suffice, a custom directive can be crafted to handle this as such

```
.directive('toggleMe', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        transclude: true,
        template: '<span id="myIcons" class="reptIcons" style="display:inline;width:50px;align:right;">' +
                ' <a title="add new folder" ng-click="nav.addAfter(nav.selectedItem)"><i class="fa fa-folder-open"></i></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;' +
                '<a title="add report here" ng-click="nav.addBelow(nav.selectedItem)"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;' +
                '<a title="remove" ng-click="nav.remove(nav.selectedItem)"><i class="fa fa-remove"></i></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;' +
                '<a title="rename" onclick="showRename(this);"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>' +
              '</span>',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {                             
        }
    }
}])
```

---

With implementation

```
<li ng-repeat="item in nav.items"> 
    <span tabindex="-1" ng-click="nav.onItemSelect(item)" ng-blur="nav.selected = null">
        <span>{{item}}</span>
        <data-toggle-me ng-show="nav.selected === item"></data-toggle-me>
    </span>
</li>
```

---

```
.controller('NavBarCtrl',['$scope', function($scope) {
    var nav = this;

    nav.items = ['Item A', 'Item B', 'Item C'];

    nav.onItemSelect = function(item) {
        nav.selected = item;  
    }           
}]);
```

### [JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/robertmazzo/zs6em650/)

Comment: you helped me initially with this, but another guy got it a bit closer. Here's his fiddle, which is working: http://jsfiddle.net/robertmazzo/zs6em650/ . the problem I was having was with the Kendo template piece, but it seems to be working with the latest Kendo libs. I'll try and post something for ya.

Comment: ah nice yes this is a way you can do it. I'll add to the answer in case other find this useful and I don't see any other SO user input on this question

Comment: @bob hey any updates for how the kendo templates were giving you some issue?